# Validate datetime in Strapi

Tags: strapi

I create DateTime picker in Strapi with the required field validation but can't save. occurring following error.

apI Parametr

```
components: []
contentType: {name: "Events", description: "", connection: "default", collectionName: "events",…}
name: "Events"
description: ""
connection: "default"
collectionName: "events"
attributes: {title: {type: "string", required: true},…}
title: {type: "string", required: true}
created_by: {nature: "oneWay", target: "plugins::users-permissions.user", dominant: false, unique: false}
image: {type: "media", multiple: false, required: true}
seo_description: {type: "text"}
seo_title: {type: "string"}
description: {type: "richtext", required: true}
calendly_url: {type: "string"}
start_date: {type: "datetime", required: true}
type: "datetime"
required: true
end_date: {type: "datetime"}
```

````
PUT http://localhost:1337/content-type-builder/content-types/application::events.events 400 (Bad Request)```
````

Comment: Can you provide the raw context of what you are sending?

Comment: hi @DerrickMehaffy I update api content parameter.

Comment: And what error do you get in the Strapi console? I'm guessing you already have data in that model before you tried setting required and your database is throwing an error because previous data is not filled in and thus cannot be required.